# Selecting elements using xpath

Tags: selenium

So very new here to Selenium but I'm having trouble selecting the element I want from this website. In this case, I got the x_path using Chrome's 'copy XPath tool.' Basically, I'm looking to extract the CID text (in this case 4004) from the website, but my code seems to be unable to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

I have also tried using the CSS selector method as well but it returns the same error.

```
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome   Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'

driver= webdriver.Chrome()

chem_name = "D008294"
url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#query=" + chem_name
driver.get(url)  


elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="collection-results-container"]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/a/span/span')

driver.close()

print(elements.text)
```

As of now, this is the error I receive: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//span[.='Compound CID']//following-sibling::a/descendant::span[2]
```

[image]

**Why your script did not worked:** I 2 issues in your code.

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="collection-results-container"]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span/a/span/span')

driver.close() # <== don't close the browser until you are done with all your steps on the browser or elements

print(elements.text) # <== you can not get text from list (python will through error here
```

**How to fix it:**

```
CID =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[.='Compound CID']//following-sibling::a/descendant::span[2]").text # <== returning the text using find_element (not find_elements)

driver.close()

print(CID) # <== now you can print `CID` though browser closed as the value already stored in variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` return list of Element. You should loop to get text of each element,

Like this:

```
for ele in print(elements.text):
    print(ele.text)
```

Or if you want to match first Element, use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath provided chrome is always does not work as expected. First you have to know how to write xpath and verify it chrome console.

see these links, which helps you to know about xpaths

https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

In this case, first find the span contains text Compound CID and move to parent span the down to child a/span/span. something like //span[contains(text(),'Compound CID']/parent::span/a/span/span.

And also you need to findelement which return single element and get text from it. If you use findelements then it will return list of elements, so you need to loop and get text from those elements.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**xpath:** //a[contains(@href, 'compound')]/span[@class='breakword']/span

you can use the "href" as your attribute reference since I noticed that it has unique value for each component.

Example:
href="https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/**substance**/53790330"
href="https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/**compound**/4004"